# Is it possible to create a customisable center point for a static Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to write the code that takes two user inputs (latitude and longitude values) and uses a Google Maps API to load up the corresponding Google Map. Is there any way to create a static Google Map that alters depending on the values entered? I have tried using the javascript API however I need the map to be brought up in an image format.

(code from comment):

```
function pos() {
  alert("Your chosen coordinates are: (" + document.getElementById("lat").value + ", " + document.getElementById("long").value + ")");
  var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
  var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("long").value);
  x = document.getElementById("button2") x.style.visibility = "visible";
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    zoom: 20,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp‌​);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a "Static Map" (image) or a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map?  What does your attempt to implement this look like?  Why is this tagged google-maps-api-2?

Comment: If a Static Map, have you looked at [the documentation for Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Locations)?

Comment: I am looking for a Static Map, the code goes:

Comment: function pos() {
    alert("Your chosen coordinates are: (" + document.getElementById("lat").value + ", " +document.getElementById("long").value + ")");
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
    var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("long").value);
    x=document.getElementById("button2")
    x.style.visibility="visible";
      
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long ),
    zoom:20,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
  }

Comment: please [edit] your question to address comments, I did that for you here (it is really hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Note that the code you posted creates a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map, not a Static Map.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the map, pass in a center object like so

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
        lat: -34,
        lng: 151
    }
}
```

Or set it later like so

```
map.setCenter({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

Answer (score 0):

Related questions:

- [Google Maps Static Map API path from KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623313/google-maps-static-map-api-path-from-kml)
- [GMap Drawing tools to image jpeg [static map URL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277220/gmap-drawing-tools-to-image-jpeg-static-map-url)

To make a static map from dynamic input, use javascript to create the URL:

```
function createStaticMap(map) {
  var staticMap = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512";
  staticMap += "&amp;maptype="+map.getMapTypeId();
  staticMap += "&amp;center="+map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
  staticMap += "&amp;zoom="+map.getZoom();
  document.getElementById('staticMap').innerHTML = staticMap;
  document.getElementById('imageholder').innerHTML = "<img src='" + staticMap + "' alt='static map' / > ";
  document.getElementById('urllen').innerHTML = "URL length =" + staticMap.length + " characters";
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rbgnr9s1/)

static map:

[image: screenshot of static map]

Google Maps Javascript API v3 map:

[image: screenshot of equivalent Google Maps Javascript API v3 map]

**code snippet:**

```css
#googleMap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
static map:
<div id="imageholder"></div>
static map URL:
<div id="staticMap"></div>
<input id="lat" value="43" />
<input id="long" value="-72" /> Google Maps Javascript API v3 map:
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<input id="button2" type="button" value="show map" />
<script>
  function pos() {
    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
    var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("long").value);
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      zoom: 20,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    createStaticMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('button2'), 'click', function() {
      var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
      var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById("long").value);
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long));
      createStaticMap(map);
    });
  }

  function createStaticMap(map) {
    var staticMap = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=500x500";
    staticMap += "&amp;maptype=" + map.getMapTypeId();
    staticMap += "&amp;center=" + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
    staticMap += "&amp;zoom=" + map.getZoom();
    document.getElementById('staticMap').innerHTML = staticMap;
    document.getElementById('imageholder').innerHTML = "<img src='" + staticMap + "' alt='static map' / > ";
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=pos"></script>
```